# PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter While using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I have java class `CourseOffered` `CourseTaker` and `Teacher` where `CourseTaker` has `Teacher`'s and `CourseOffered`'s primary key as it's foreign key.

The `CourseOffered` Class Looks Following,( I have removed some basic `constructors` and `Getters` and `Setters` for make it small;)

```
package subHibernate.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course_offered")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseOffered.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseOffered c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseOffered.findByCourseId", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseOffered c WHERE c.courseId = :courseId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseOffered.findByCourseCode", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseOffered c WHERE c.courseCode = :courseCode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseOffered.findByCourseTitle", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseOffered c WHERE c.courseTitle = :courseTitle"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseOffered.findBySession", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseOffered c WHERE c.session = :session"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseOffered.findBySemester", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseOffered c WHERE c.semester = :semester")})
public class CourseOffered implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private Integer courseId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "course_code")
    private String courseCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "course_title")
    private String courseTitle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "session")
    private String session;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "semester")
    private String semester;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "caCourseId")
    private List<CourseTaker> courseTakerList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "crCourseId")
    private List<CourseRegistration> courseRegistrationList;

    public CourseOffered() {
    }

    //Some Constructors
    // Getters and Setters which I deliberately Ignored as they are not 
    // Important here 

    @XmlTransient
    public List<CourseTaker> getCourseTakerList() {
        return courseTakerList;
    }

    public void setCourseTakerList(List<CourseTaker> courseTakerList) {
        this.courseTakerList = courseTakerList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<CourseRegistration> getCourseRegistrationList() {
        return courseRegistrationList;
    }

    public void setCourseRegistrationList(List<CourseRegistration> courseRegistrationList) {
        this.courseRegistrationList = courseRegistrationList;
    }

    public java.lang.Integer getPrimaryKey(){
        return getCourseId();
    }

}
```

And `Teacher` class looks like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findByTeacherId", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t WHERE t.teacherId = :teacherId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findByTeaCode", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t WHERE t.teaCode = :teaCode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findByTeaPassword", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t WHERE t.teaPassword = :teaPassword"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findByTeaName", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t WHERE t.teaName = :teaName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findByTeaEmail", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t WHERE t.teaEmail = :teaEmail"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Teacher.findByTeaDegignation", query = "SELECT t FROM Teacher t WHERE t.teaDegignation = :teaDegignation")})
public class Teacher implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private Integer teacherId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tea_code")
    private String teaCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tea_password")
    private String teaPassword;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tea_name")
    private String teaName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tea_email")
    private String teaEmail;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tea_degignation")
    private String teaDegignation;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "caTeacherId")
    private List<CourseTaker> courseTakerList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tgTeacherId")
    private List<TeacherGroup> teacherGroupList;
    public Teacher() {
}

    // Some Constructors
    // Getters And Setters Ignored

    @XmlTransient
    public List<CourseTaker> getCourseTakerList() {
        return courseTakerList;
    }

    public void setCourseTakerList(List<CourseTaker> courseTakerList) {
        this.courseTakerList = courseTakerList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<TeacherGroup> getTeacherGroupList() {
        return teacherGroupList;
    }

    public void setTeacherGroupList(List<TeacherGroup> teacherGroupList) {
        this.teacherGroupList = teacherGroupList;
    }
}
```

And Finally `CourseTaker` Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course_taker")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseTaker.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM CourseTaker c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CourseTaker.findByCourseTakerId", query = "SELECT c FROM   CourseTaker c WHERE c.courseTakerId = :courseTakerId")})
public class CourseTaker implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "course_taker_id")
    private Integer courseTakerId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ca_course_id", referencedColumnName = "course_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private CourseOffered caCourseId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ca_teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "teacher_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Teacher caTeacherId;

    public CourseTaker() {
    }

    public CourseTaker(Integer courseTakerId) {
        this.courseTakerId = courseTakerId;
    }

    public Integer getCourseTakerId() {
        return courseTakerId;
    }

    public void setCourseTakerId(Integer courseTakerId) {
        this.courseTakerId = courseTakerId;
    }

    public CourseOffered getCaCourseId() {
        return caCourseId;
    }

    public void setCaCourseId(CourseOffered caCourseId) {
        this.caCourseId = caCourseId;
    }

    public Teacher getCaTeacherId() {
        return caTeacherId;
    }

    public void setCaTeacherId(Teacher caTeacherId) {
        this.caTeacherId = caTeacherId;
    }
}
```

I also Have a `CourseTakerService` Class which looks like this,

```
public class CourseTakerService implements ICourseTakerService ,   LocatableService {

    private static Logger log = LogService.getLogger(CourseTakerService.class);

    public void init() {
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
       /**
    * Adds a new courseTaker to the database.
    *
    * @param model a data object
    * @return CourseTaker a data object with the primary key
    */
    public subHibernate.entity.CourseTaker   addCourseTaker(subHibernate.entity.CourseTaker model) throws GenericBusinessException {
    subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper hibernateTemplate = new subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper();
    try {
        hibernateTemplate.save(model);
        return getCourseTaker(model.getPrimaryKey());
    } finally {
        log.debug("finished addCourseTaker(subHibernate.entity.CourseTaker model)");
    }
    /**
    *
    * Retrieves a list of data object for the specified caTeacherId field. To
    * use a wildcard search, use a % in the query.
    *
    * @param caTeacherId the field
    * @return List of CourseTaker data objects, empty list in case no results
    * were found.
    */
    public java.util.List findCourseTakerByCaTeacherId(java.lang.Integer caTeacherId) throws GenericBusinessException {
    subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper hibernateTemplate = new subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper();
    try {
        String queryString = "from " + CourseTaker.class.getName() + " e where e.caTeacherId like :caTeacherId ";
        // Add a an order by on all primary keys to assure reproducable results.
        String orderByPart = "";
        orderByPart += " order by e.courseTakerId";
        queryString += orderByPart;
        Query query = hibernateTemplate.createQuery(queryString);
        hibernateTemplate.setQueryParameter(query, "caTeacherId", caTeacherId);
        List list = hibernateTemplate.list(query);
        return list;
        } finally {
            log.debug("finished findCourseTakerByCaTeacherId(java.lang.Integer caTeacherId)");
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `list = (List) courseTakerService.findCourseTakerByCaTeacherId(1);`
It produces the following **Stack Trace**
[It is **Guaranteed** that courseTaker table has a row with courseTeacherId = **1** ]

```
    27-Feb-2015 11:11:31.539 ERROR [http-nio-8084-exec-32]   com.finalist.util.log.JDKLogger.error Error while getting the hibernate query list.
    org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by  reflection getter of subHibernate.entity.Teacher.teacherId
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4537)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4259)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:209)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:248)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:510)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:612)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper.list(HibernateQueryHelper.java:94)
at subHibernate.session.CourseTakerService.findCourseTakerByCaTeacherId(CourseTakerService.java:270)
at OffiAssignServlet.processRequest(OffiAssignServlet.java:116)
at OffiAssignServlet.doPost(OffiAssignServlet.java:174)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field subHibernate.entity.Teacher.teacherId to java.lang.Integer
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:59)
... 53 more

subHibernate.exception.GenericBusinessException: Error while getting the hibernate query list.
at subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper.list(HibernateQueryHelper.java:98)
at subHibernate.session.CourseTakerService.findCourseTakerByCaTeacherId(CourseTakerService.java:270)
at OffiAssignServlet.processRequest(OffiAssignServlet.java:116)
at OffiAssignServlet.doPost(OffiAssignServlet.java:174)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of subHibernate.entity.Teacher.teacherId
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:344)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4537)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4259)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:209)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:248)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:510)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:612)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at subHibernate.HibernateQueryHelper.list(HibernateQueryHelper.java:94)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field subHibernate.entity.Teacher.teacherId to java.lang.Integer
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:59)
... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query string need to be changed like below.Please try with this.

e.caTeacherId will refer to the Teacher object and u r comparing with the teacherId value.This might be the problem.

```
    String queryString = "from " + CourseTaker.class.getName() + " e where e.caTeacherId.teacherId like :caTeacherId ";
```

Comment: Wao.. Thanks, It worked. :) However, can you please explain it in some detail so  that I can Understand it well. I have some questions, Like in my `Teacher` Class I have ` `teacher_id` as a column name. So Shouldn't it be like `String queryString = "from " + CourseTaker.class.getName() + " e where e.caTeacherId.teacher_id like :caTeacherId ";`

Comment: No.When writing hibernate queries,you have to refer only to the respective java fields defined.